# Physic engine for sandy 3d

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sandy3d

I develop a small game to learn AS and sandy 3D. I want to include a physic engine in my 3D scene. I wanted to use WOW like the sandy tutorial say but the WOW web site is down so it's difficult to develop something without doc.

I search a new physic engine that I can use with sandy 3D.

Do you now that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [ActionScript Physics Engine](http://www.cove.org/ape/)?

Oops, that is a 2D engine. That's not what you want. How about [Jiglib Flash](http://www.jiglibflash.com)